# glDrawElements vs glDrawArrays for polygons that do not reuse vertices

Tags: opengl, performance

Is it better to use `glDrawElements` or `glDrawArrays` when **not** reusing vertices?  There must be some difference, otherwise people would always use `glDrawElements`?

I suppose the question could be reworded as the following:

Does `glDrawElements` function the same as `glDrawArrays` if it is passed a blank indices table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`glDrawElements()` doesn't support a "blank indices table".  `glDrawElements()` must always be given explicit data about in what order vertex indices are to be drawn, either using a pointer to a memory buffer (OpenGL <= 2.1 only), or an offset into a bound VBO.

`glDrawArrays()` acts like `glDrawElements()` would if it had been given an array of values [0, 1, 2, ... , n], where 'n' is the `count` value passed into either function.

In theory, `glDrawArrays()` requires less data than `glDrawElements()` (in that the order of indices is implicit, instead of requiring a block of data to be transferred to the GPU), and so it should be marginally faster if your data is in that format.  But in practice, the difference is unlikely to be worth worrying about.

Comment: Oh of course. I should not have rushed when writing this, by "blank indices table" I meant a table of indices that would not have any reused indices (0, 1, 2, 3). But this is the exact answer I was looking for! Much appreciated, Trevor.